# prompt de comando fechando instantaneamente

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, prompt

Estou programando em C e usando o Code Runner para executar o código, mas sempre que eu clico em executar, o prompt de comando abre e fecha muito rapidamente.
O problema é com o prompt de comando fechando sozinho, pois quando dou um comando pra receber um valor o prompt espera eu digitar algo.

Comment: Por acaso ele está executando o programa e fechando a tela? Se for coloque ao final uma instrução de leitura do tipo: `printf("Tecle algo para encerrar: "); gets(x);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é normal e inclusive esperado.

O prompt fica aberto enquanto seu programa está em execução, ao final ele fecha.

---

Você pode criar formas dele não fechar de forma imediata, é bem comum utilizar a função `getchar()` como teste, antes do `return` da `main`, assim o programa aguarda a tecla *ENTER* sem pressionada para encerrar:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("Hello world\n");
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Com isso, será exibido os dados no prompt, mas a função `getchar` vai *segurar* a execução.

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/MedicalCriticalExperiments

---

Você pode acabar encontrando exemplos que utilizam `system("pause")`, isso também vai segurar a execução do programa, mas só vai funcionar em Windows.